# ViewModel Handling Events

Tags: wpf, mvvm

I saw an question here where OP asked about binding events to ViewModel. Basically ViewModel shall respresent an abstract View containing necessary data from Model so that the View may be also able to use Bindings. But to be able to fullfill all that the ViewModel must also conver most of the use cases which are happening in the View such as example if search textbox is empty the search button shall be greyed out. That works fine but lets add events to the game. It would be way easier if Button.Click where bindable to an EventHandler in ViewModel and inside the event handler you would be then able to use model objects.

Now my question is since WPF supports event driven programming why cant events be handled in ViewModel? How could I provide binding events funcionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Event handlers would sit in the view's code behind file. If you're using MVVM, then you'll want to minimise the amount of code in a code behind file.

WPF supports commanding, and the [ICommand](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.icommand.aspx) interface includes a `CanExecute` and `Execute` method. There are implementations of `ICommand` which allow these methods to be implemented on the view model.

Having said that, commanding also has its limitations, so [you should consider using an MVVM framework when using MVVM](http://www.lhotka.net/weblog/UsingTheMVVMPatternRequiresAFramework.aspx). Something like [Caliburn.Micro](http://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/) comes with [Actions](https://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=All%20About%20Actions) which also allow verbs on the view model to be invoked based on control events.

Comment: You are right. There are other frameworks that come with Action and stuff like that but still. Its very common that once you click on a button you need some extra information from model to do some certain validations or something like that and it kinda sounds like a workaround if you use attached properties or attached commands just to do that small task. And all that just because binding events doesnt work.

Comment: Binding events does work, but as I say the handlers would sit in the view's code behind. MVVM is a design pattern achievable in WPF, but that requires some implementations that aren't provided out of the box. Therefore, it is highly highly recommended that you use an MVVM framework to avoid attempting to re-implement the work already done to an extremely high standard. MVVM frameworks don't just solve the commanding issue, but a whole collection of issues that you would face if you tried to implement MVVM alone.

Comment: Can you provide few links about that? Just in case somebody stumbles upon this question on the internet.

Comment: The best link is the one already provided from Rocky Lhotka, the developer of the CSLA business object framework.

Comment: I have a question; why Caliburn.Micro when you can use Prism? Do you have experience using the both. I am releatively new to MVVM and decided to build everything I needed from scratch. I got a long way doing this but the task is a redundant one, why re-invent the wheel etc. However, I have continued and have a fully MVVM application built without a MVVM framework. Needless to say I will never do it again, but I have learnt A LOT. Next time I plan to use Prism - but why is Caliburn.Micro better than Microsofts own brand? Thanks for your time...

Comment: Well it's subjective and they are different beasts. Caliburn.Micro is a pure MVVM framework with a powerful convention over configuration approach, full screen lifecyle, and Actions which are extremely powerful. MVVM in Prism is achievable, but it's not its only concern, it's also tailored towards developing composite applications. View composition is another consideration and Caliburn.Micro provides a very simple convention based approach.

Answer (score 1):

It is because the use of event explicitly breaks the MVVM pattern (as I am sure you are aware). However there is another way around this - by using the [Attached Command Behaviour pattern](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/28959/Introduction-to-Attached-Behaviors-in-WPF). More information [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/johngossman/archive/2008/05/07/the-attached-behavior-pattern.aspx).

Code for a small but great framework for attached commands is downloadable from [here](http://marlongrech.wordpress.com/2008/12/13/attachedcommandbehavior-v2-aka-acb/).

I hope this helps.

---

Edit. attached behaviour allow you to use events without breaking the MVVM pattern. The use is like

```
<Border Background="Yellow" Width="350" Margin="0,0,10,0" Height="35" CornerRadius="2" x:Name="test"> 
    <local:CommandBehaviorCollection.Behaviors>
        <local:BehaviorBinding Event="MouseLeftButtonDown" 
                               Action="{Binding DoSomething}" 
                               CommandParameter="An Action on MouseLeftButtonDown"/> 
        <local:BehaviorBinding Event="MouseRightButtonDown" 
                               Command="{Binding SomeCommand}" 
                               CommandParameter="A Command on MouseRightButtonDown"/>
    </local:CommandBehaviorCollection.Behaviors> 
    <TextBlock Text="MouseDown on this border to execute the command"/> 
</Border>
```

Comment: Thanks. I am aware of MVVM pattern just still I was wondering since like I mentioned in my question the MVVM pattern means keep View and Model sparate but use ViewModel that contains data from Model and represents an abstract View with its custom logic. Now the View has events, why cant those be handled in ViewModel since ViewModel contains most of View logic anyways?

Comment: Bacause, by design, event handlers for a UI component or 'View' has to be contained in the 'View's' code behind - this is what breaks the MVVM pattern. What I have said above is that you _can_ have your cake (MVVM) and eat it (using attached Commands) to replicat the use of event handlers. I will update my answer to provide a usage example...

Comment: I get you. I dont want to steal your time with an example with code. This is more a disscussion. Commands are awesome anyways except the fact that you only may place one command on an control while you may have 100 different events eg. for text input, for clicking, for mouse over.

Comment: Well with attached commands you can wire up as many events as you like to ICommands themselves _without_ destroying your MVVM. Take a look at the small example above...

Comment: Yea attached commands do the job. I was talking about wpf by design. :) Thanks for the example. There is just that small think that annoys me when I think about attached commands. I have been using them for a while. I think a year ago and I realized back then that the events who trigger Command.Execute are created dynamically annonymously and once you change the datacontext they dont get released hence why back then i wasnt able to despose an old datacontext object properly.